# Update method passes the old value instead of the new value in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, put

I am trying to make an Update method and everything works fine except for a value that is selected from a drop-down-list. When the `PUT` method is called, the API always receives the old value instead of the newly selected one.

This is the list I am talking about:
**edituser.component.html**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose a role </mat-label>
    <mat-select *ngIf="roles" [(ngModel)]="userRoleID" name="role">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.id" [(ngModel)]="el.userRoleID">{{role.role}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**edituser.component.ts**

```
export class EdituserComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  sub: any;
  user: User[];
  roles: Role[];
  userRoleID: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService, private router:Router, private roleService:RoleService) {
    this.roleService.getRoles().subscribe((result) => {
      this.roles = result
      this.useRoles(this.roles);
    });
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      console.log(this.id);
      this.userService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe((result) => this.user = result);
    });
  }

  updateUser(user: User){
    this.userService.updateUser(user).subscribe(
      (result: User) => {
        this.userService.getUsers();
      });
      this.router.navigateByUrl("");
  }

  useRoles(roles:any)
  {
    console.log(roles);
  }
}
```

Why does it keep passing the wrong, outdated value to the API when trying to update?

Comment: Can you please tell the class structure of the `User`  and `Role`? And also tell me what is  `[(ngModel)]="el.userRoleID"` ? Please give me some extra HTML code and ts to check the problem. :)

Comment: you are using value and ngModel together. Don't do that, use one or the other. it's also not clear where you are calling `updateUser`